# Could be a problem with the group_map command?

Tags: r, dplyr

I wanted to use `group_by` and `group_map` from the dplyr package instead of `split` and `map`. However, I ran into a rather strange problem.

I do that

```
library(dplyr)

df = tibble(
  name = rep(c("a", "b", "c"), 100),
  x = rep(1:100, each=3),
  y = rnorm(300)
)

f1 = function(df, par1 = FALSE, par2 = FALSE){
  paste(par1, par2, df$name[1], mean(df$y))
}
```

Now, if I run such commands, everything looks fine

```
df %>% 
  split(.$name) %>% 
  map(f1)
```

```
$a
[1] "FALSE FALSE a -0.111419050033957"

$b
[1] "FALSE FALSE b -0.0715780638158137"

$c
[1] "FALSE FALSE c 0.13736619417831"
```

If I set the optional parameters, everything is still fine

```
df %>% 
  split(.$name) %>% 
  map(f1, par1 = TRUE, par2 = TRUE)
```

```
$a
[1] "TRUE TRUE a -0.111419050033957"

$b
[1] "TRUE TRUE b -0.0715780638158137"

$c
[1] "TRUE TRUE c 0.13736619417831"
```

When I try to get the same effect using `group_by` and `group_map` something is wrong

```
df %>% 
  group_by(name) %>% 
  group_map(f1, .keep = TRUE)
```

```
[[1]]
[1] "a FALSE a -0.111419050033957"

[[2]]
[1] "b FALSE b -0.0715780638158137"

[[3]]
[1] "c FALSE c 0.13736619417831"
```

As you can see, the optional parameter `par1` receives values that are the name of the data group. This is not what I expected!

If I set `par1` then `par2` get these values.

```
df %>% 
  group_by(name) %>% 
  group_map(f1, par1 = TRUE, .keep = TRUE)
```

```
[[1]]
[1] "TRUE a a -0.111419050033957"

[[2]]
[1] "TRUE b b -0.0715780638158137"

[[3]]
[1] "TRUE c c 0.13736619417831"
```

But when I try to set both optional parameters, I get an error!

```
df %>% 
  group_by(name) %>% 
  group_map(f1, par1 = TRUE, par2 = TRUE, .keep = TRUE)
```

```
Error in (function (df, par1 = FALSE, par2 = FALSE)  : 
  unused argument (dots[[2]][[1]])
```

I must admit that I am surprised by such behavior of the function `group_map`.
Is it really the way it should work, or am I doing something wrong or I have a bad understanding of something.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a function name in the `.f` argument of `dplyr::group_map`. But then you have to keep in mind that the function in `.f` must at least take two arguments: `.x` the first argument which is the `data.frame` and `.y` a `tibble` containing the grouping variables.

The documentation says this in the details section:

> Each conceptual group of the data frame is exposed to the function .f
> with two pieces of information:
>
> The subset of the data for the group, exposed as .x.
>
> The key, a tibble with exactly one row and columns for each grouping
> variable, exposed as .y.

`.x` and `.y` will always be the first two argument to the function in `.f` and this is causing your problem as we can see from the error message:

```r
df %>% 
  group_by(name) %>% 
  group_map(.f = f1,
            par1 = TRUE,
            par2 = TRUE,
            .keep = TRUE)

#> Error in (function (df, par1 = FALSE, par2 = FALSE) : unused argument (dots[[2]][[1]])
```

Here `.y` is passed to your function `f1` which has no argument to match it.

Lets rewrite your function `f1` so that it takes `.y`, the group name (`grp_nm`) as  second argument. We will just use this argument to print out to see what `.y` is:

```r
library(dplyr)

df = tibble(
  name = rep(c("a", "b", "c"), 100),
  x = rep(1:100, each=3),
  y = rnorm(300)
)

f1 = function(df, grp_nm, par1 = FALSE, par2 = FALSE){
  print(grp_nm)
  paste(par1, par2, df$name[1], mean(df$y))
}

df %>% 
  group_by(name) %>% 
  group_map(.f = f1,
            par1 = TRUE,
            par2 = TRUE,
            .keep = TRUE)

#> # A tibble: 1 x 1
#>   name 
#>   <chr>
#> 1 a    
#> # A tibble: 1 x 1
#>   name 
#>   <chr>
#> 1 b    
#> # A tibble: 1 x 1
#>   name 
#>   <chr>
#> 1 c

#> [[1]]
#> [1] "TRUE TRUE a -0.0371737353510479"
#> 
#> [[2]]
#> [1] "TRUE TRUE b -0.00874656816210368"
#> 
#> [[3]]
#> [1] "TRUE TRUE c -0.030588993215492"
```

<sup>Created on 2021-08-25 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Of course we do not need the `grp_nm` argument, so the easiest way is just to add the ellipsis `...` to your function which will prevent the error seen above:

```
f1 = function(df, ..., par1 = FALSE, par2 = FALSE){
  paste(par1, par2, df$name[1], mean(df$y))
}
```

So there is no bug to report here `dplyr::group_map` is working as expected.

Comment: I haven't read it! I really missed this argument `.y`. Thanks!